# INotifyPropertyChanged & INotifyCollectionChanged for datamodels

Tags: c#, .net-5

Lets say I have a simple dataclass that I'm using to send data over a websocket:

```
class Person
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int Age { get; set; }
    public List<Person> Relatives { get; set; }
}
```

I'm serializing to JSON for the websocket communication.

Now I have a Gui to visualize all the data in WPF and I want to use databinding and the same Person class for the GUI as I'm using to transfer the data between client and server to save myself from doubling all the code.

Usually I would simply implement `INotifyPropertyChanged` on the properties and use a `ObservableCollection<Person>` instead of a `List<Person>`. But this seems wrong to me. The server does not need the `INotifyPropertyChanged` and `ObservableCollection` overhead. But I also don't want to rewrite the classes as a BindablePerson.

Is there a preferred way to get around this issue?

Comment: Maybe you implement `INotifyPropertyChanged ` with flag enabling/disabling raising events and turn it on only when going to UI?

Comment: This would work for the properties, but how about the `List<Person>`?

Comment: You can subclass ObservableCollection of T and override this methods:
        protected override void OnCollectionChanged(NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            if (PreventEvents)
                return;
            base.OnCollectionChanged(e);
        }

        protected override void OnPropertyChanged(PropertyChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            if (PreventEvents)
                return;
            base.OnPropertyChanged(e);
        }

Comment: But this still does not give the same functionality like a List<T>. And it seems like there must be an easier way, I can't be the only one facing this issue?
I guess I would rather create a BindablePerson than overriding ObservableCollection.

Comment: Choosing the best way how to work with collections is completely on you, it depends on many things in your architecture. Good luck with implementation.